# JQueryのトースト、紹介されたページのように表示されない。

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

http://kdemos.github.io/jquery-toast-plugin
こちらのサイトでは自分が実装したいトーストの形式をパラメータ入力することで
プラグインのライブラリが、目標どおりに表示されるよう
その実行文（JQuery）まで　表示・提供してくれるようになっています（多分そういう意図）。

サイトでは試しにパラメータで指定した形式のトーストも表示することができるようになっています。
早速このサイト上で実装された実行文を、手元で開発中のWebページに適用してみたのですが
思い通りの表示になってくれません。

ダイアログのような小窓でトーストが現れてくることを期待していましたが
以下のようなブロック要素？！的な表示で現れてきます。
（トップ真ん中に表れるように指定しても、ボトムに表れてくるし．．．）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

====質問====
自身のWebページのHTMLorCSSに問題がある、とは思うのですが一体何が問題と考えられるのでしょうか？
大まかにいってしまえば
HTMLのbodyの中には、
二つのdivが直下に構成されている感じです。
form要素を包むメインのdiv、その下にモーダルウィンドウ用のdivが控えられている、そんな感じです。

ご見解を頂けますと幸いです、よろしくお願い致します。
以下、トーストのライブラリの実行文です。

-JQuery-

```
$.toast({
    text: "登録できる状態です。",
    showHideTransition: "fade",
    allowToastClose: false,
    hideAfter: 3000,
    stack: 1,
    position: "top-center",
    bgColor: "#444444",
    textColor: "#eeeeee",
    textAlign: "center",
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/kamranahmedse/jquery-toast-plugin/tree/master/dist
cssは取り込んでいるでしょうか？

https://github.com/kamranahmedse/jquery-toast-plugin
もし、こちらのHow to useを見ていないのであれば一読されることをお勧めします。

Comment: hiro様　早速のご見解をありがとうございました。すみません、PHP側のCSSの参照を誤っておりました、お騒がせしました。